# x^2 operator for raising a vector to the second power is not working

Tags: r, plot, pca

I'm trying to plot a scree for PCA of a data with the following code:

```r
library(ade4)
data("olympic")
pca.olympic <- princomp(olympic$tab)
plot(1:10, pca.olympic$sdevˆ2, type="b", xlab="# PCs", ylab="Variance of PC",
     main="PCA of Covariance Matrix")
```

When I run this code I get the following output:

[image: img1]

When I should be seeing something like this instead:

[image: img2]

Can someone explain how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Your symbol for power `ˆ` is not correct.
I am not sure how you typed it, but copy and use this one: `^` instead. Note that it is visually different - a different symbol.

When you use the the one you have in your code R silently returns `NULL`:

```
pca.olympic$sdevˆ2
NULL
```

This is because `ˆ` you typed is treated as just another character, not an operator, in the same way something like `š` would be treated. As a result the expression `pca.olympic$sdevˆ2` is not raising the element named `sdev` to the power of 2, but looking for a variable named `sdevˆ2`. Since such a variable does not exist - it returns NULL.

Now, when `y` is null the plot is only produced with the `x` (`1:10`) variable plotted on both axes.
And you get a diagonal line.

Answer (score 3):

Replace  `^` operator by `**` operator to raise the eigenvalues to the power of 2:

```
library(ade4)

data("olympic")
pca.olympic <- princomp(olympic$tab)
plot(1:10, pca.olympic$sdev ** 2, type="b", xlab="# PCs", ylab="Variance of PC",
     main="PCA of Covariance Matrix")
```

[image]